# Passing commands to OS: What is wrong here?

Tags: python, bash, operating-system

So, I want to create a simple script to create directories based upon the file names contained within a certain folder.

My method looks like this:

```
def make_new_folders(filenames, destination):
    """
    Take a list of presets and create new directories using mkdir
    """
    for filename in filenames:
        path = '"%s/%s/"' %  (destination, filename)
        subprocess.call(["mkdir", path])
```

For some reason I can't get the command to work.

If I pass in a file named "Test Folder", i get an error such as:

```
mkdir: "/Users/soundteam/Desktop/PlayGround/Test Folder: No such file or directory
```

Printing the 'path' variable results in:
    "/Users/soundteam/Desktop/PlayGround/Test Folder/"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: make sure you use -p option with mkdir, in case `/Users/soundteam/Desktop/PlayGround` folder is not present

Comment: On a side note, consider using `os.mkdir` or `os.makedirs` rather than calling the external mkdir command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the double quotes. `subprocess` passes the parameters directly to the process, so you don't need to prepare them for parsing by a shell. You also don't need the trailing slash, and should use os.path.join to combine path components:

```
path = os.path.join(destination, filename)
```

**EDIT:** You should accept @Fabian's answer, which explains that you don't need subprocess at all (I knew that).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should use `os.path.join()` to glue your path parts together because it works cross-platform.

Furthermore, there are built-in commands like [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir) or [os.makedirs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) (which is really cool because it's recursive) to create folders. Creating a subprocess is expensive and, in this case, not a good idea.

In your example you're passing double-quotes (`"destination/filename"`) to subprocess, which you don't have to do. Terminals need double-quotes if you use whitespaces in file or folder names, subprocess takes care of that for you.